# Mapa abre bugado

Tags: html, angularjs, css3, angularjs-directives, maps

Bom dia!

Tenho uma aplicação web, onde utilizo um mapa leafletjs (http://tombatossals.github.io/angular-leaflet-directive/#!/) e openstreetmap como tile.

O mapa funciona de forma perfeita, consigo interagir de qualquer forma (adicionar marcadores, criar layers, zoom..), porém, quando acesso a página onde está o map, ele não carrega de forma correta, conforme printscreen abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ele se reajusta quando eu redimensiono a janela ou abro e fecho o console, segue imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Códigos:

View:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="box_whiteframe_map">
        <leaflet ng-init="vm.buscaEnderecoClientesEmpresas()" center="vm.center" defaults="vm.defaults" markers="vm.markers" width="100%" height="480px"></leaflet>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS/SASS:

```
.box_whiteframe_map {
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .14), 0 2px 1px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .12);
    color: #000;
    margin: 0;
    clear: both;
}
```

Controller:

```
        /* MAP */
    vm.markers = new Array();

    vm.buscaEnderecoClientesEmpresas = function() {
        vm.items = loadSaas(Cookies.get('crm_o2_hash')); // carregar saas id
        vm.items.then(function(items) { // ler array de retorno
            vm.saasid = items;
            var dados = {
                'saasid': vm.saasid
            }
            relatoriosService.carregarEnderecoClientesEmpresas(dados).then(function(response) {
                if (response.data != 'null') {
                    vm.enderecoClientesEmpresas = response.data;
                    angular.forEach(vm.enderecoClientesEmpresas, function(value, key) {
                        if (value.tipo == 'p'){
                            var icon = 'user';
                        } else {
                            var icon = 'cog';
                        }
                        vm.markers.push({
                            group: value.cidade,
                            lat: value.lat_lng.lat,
                            lng: value.lat_lng.lng,
                            message: value.nome,
                            icon: {
                                type: 'awesomeMarker',
                                icon: icon,
                                markerColor: 'blue'
                            },
                            label: {
                                options: {
                                    noHide: true
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    });
                } else {
                    vm.enderecoClientesEmpresas = '';
                }

            }, function(error) {
                console.log('Erro findSemEmail: ', error);
            });
        });
    }

    angular.extend(vm, { // EXTENDE AS PROPRIEDADES DO MAPA (MARCADORES, LOCALIZAÇÃO INCIAL..)


        center: { // LOCALIZAÇÃO INICIAL  .
            lat: -22.952419,
            lng: -43.211667,
            zoom: 4
        },
        defaults: {
            tileLayer: "http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
            zoomControlPosition: 'topright',
            tileLayerOptions: {
                opacity: 0.9,
                detectRetina: true,
                reuseTiles: true,
                attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> | &copy <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">Funil PRÓ</a>',
            },
            scrollWheelZoom: true,
            minZoom: 3,
            worldCopyJump: true
        }
    });

    /* MAP FINAL */
```

Alguma ajuda?

Comment: Pode nos mostrar algum código?

Comment: Adicionado!!!!!

Comment: Eu acredito que passei por um problema parecido e resolvi utilizando um `timeout` e chamando o método `invalidateSize()`. Exemplo: `$timeout(ctrl.map.invalidateSize());`. A variável `ctrl.map` é o meu objeto do Mapa (L.Map). Assim, após o carregamento do Angular, do Document, ele vai executar esse método e dar um _resize_ no mapa.

Comment: Geralmente este problema acontece quando o mapa carregou primeiro que algo ou você colocou o mapa em algum elemento do html que está/estava invisivel.  A solução para os dois problemas é dar um resize no mapa. No primeiro caso você dá um resize depois de onde você tem certeza que o mapa já foi completamente "configurado" e no segundo caso você deve colocar um resize TODAS as vezes que você exibir o elemento escondido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver da seguinte forma:

```
    vm.esconderMostrarMapa = false;

    vm.mostrarMapa = function () {
        $timeout(function() {
            vm.esconderMostrarMapa = true;
        }, 500); 
    }
```

O mapa inicia como false, aí quando fica true o mesmo é mostrado na tela. Sei que não a melhor forma seria utilizando o `invalidateSize()`, mas vendo as issues no github do lefalet angularjs, várias pessoas estão com esse mesmo problema e não conseguiram resolver utilizando o mesmo.

Outra forma mais correta é utilizando o método map.invalidateSize:

```
        vm.ajustarMapa = function(){
      leafletData.getMap().then(function(map) {
        setTimeout(function(){
          map.invalidateSize();
        }, 200);
      });
    };

    vm.ajustarMapa();
```